# HttpWebRequest very slow

Tags: c#, tcp, webrequest

I have been running a C# TCP server, which is transferring data to another server via HTTP POST calls for 2 years with no issues.

After switching from Windows server 2008 to 2012, the requests are taking forever. On the "receiving" side, it is so slow, that I am running out of threads and getting 508 errors back. I have timed the scripts which is requested via HTTP. It takes around 30-40 ms to execute. No worries. 
If I time the amount of time it takes to make the `HttpWebRequest` it is around 2 seconds, which must be why I am running out of threads on the web server.

This is my request code:

```
public static string WRequest(string URL, string method, string postData)
{
    string responseData = "";
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;

        // System.Net.CookieContainer cookieJar = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwrequest =
          (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
       // hwrequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        hwrequest.Accept = "*/*";
        hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1";
        hwrequest.Timeout = 60000;
        hwrequest.Proxy = null;
        hwrequest.Method = method;
        if (hwrequest.Method == "POST")
        {
            hwrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Use UTF8Encoding instead of ASCIIEncoding for XML requests:
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] postByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length;
            System.IO.Stream postStream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream();
            postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();
        }

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwresponse =
          (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)hwrequest.GetResponse();

        if (hwresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            System.IO.Stream responseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader =
              new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
            responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            // MessageBox.Show(responseData);
        }
        hwresponse.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        responseData = "An error occurred: " + e.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(responseData);

    return responseData;
}
```

I have tested this on my windows 10 machine, and the server 2012, with the same timing problems (2 seconds).

Any ideas to where the problem might be? I feel like I have tried everything.

Comment: What happens if you set `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;` to `true`?

Comment: Before debugging this, you really should put `using`s around all those request and response streams.

Comment: Does it improve if you set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;`?

Comment: For testing purposes, can you try using the ipv4 address of the intended endpoint instead of a hostname?  I've had issues in the past where it tried to use ipv6 and it adds about 1 second to the overall request due to this.

Comment: mjwills - Does not change anything
Matthew - I can't get the direct IP, since it is a hosted service, so they are using DNS to route from domain